# DeploymentException with JBoss 6

Tags: jboss6.x

While Deploying ear in jboss 6 its giving Runtime Exception please help me how to solve this error

```
11:14:14,684 ERROR [ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: FirstGen.ear: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(FirstGen.ear)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1106) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:417) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:367) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:277) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.addDeployment(MainDeployerPlugin.java:77) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.addDeployment(ProfileControllerContext.java:133) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:132) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_27]
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: FirstGen.ear
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:300) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.determineStructure(AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.java:60) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:197) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:222) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77) [:2.2.0.GA]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: xml_stream@14,15
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:224) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:193) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:171) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:169) [:6.0.0.Final]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The content of element type "application" must match "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)". @ *unknown*[14,15]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.error(SaxJBossXBParser.java:416) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:209) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    ... 41 more

Answer (score 0):

The order of the display-name and description elements in application.xml was changed between J2EE 1.3 and 1.4 (with the move from DTDs to schema).

This message:

```
The content of element type "application" must match "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)
```

tells me that you have an incorrectly formed J2EE 1.3 application.xml file with:

```
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
```

at the top.

I suggest you update this to a more modern schema such as:

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
      version="5">
```

for JBossAS 6.

The order of your elements will then be correct.

Comment: Please can you give Jboss 6 sample Ear structure simple application